# TextArea element - default size to fit content

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I set a fixed width on a textarea element is there an elegant way of setting the height default to a size that would allow all it's content to fit?

I was hoping to avoid hard-coding anything in jquery that would compare text.length and try to equate a value to a height, but maybe that is the only way, i'd love to see some native css rule if possible but I can't seem to think of any off the top of my head.

I've created a fiddle illustrating what I am trying to accomplish.
http://jsfiddle.net/edZgm/

here's the code:

CSS:

```
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('textarea')
        .width(500);

    //I have a width set, but see how the height defaults to a rediculously small amount.
    //I'd like to have the height default to fit everything on load.

});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea> ... lots of text </textarea>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe it's do-able (with jQuery, not CSS), but difficult. I think you can resize the height of the textarea with jquery after the page and textarea content loads, and then calculate the height needed by counting characters & lines of text, but that depends highly on your font and CSS for that text. It would be easier if you used a fixed-width font.

Comment: You might want to see what `autogrow` plugin does in jQuery.

Comment: ah that's a good point i wasn't even thinking of font size. Hmm then it'd almost certainly have to be JS/JQ based... one would need to probably look at font-size and line-height, then determine content length and determine how many chars would fit per line, calculate the number of lines, and figure a height based on line number multiplied by the line-height.

Comment: haha as i was typing that, i was thinking... man I should write a plugin that monitors every keystroke and resizes the textarea per entry if necessary

Comment: @karthikr thk you, this is right on the money as to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the comment an answer for future reference:

Checkout [jquery-autogrow](https://github.com/akaihola/jquery-autogrow)

Answer (score 3):

There is this jQuery plugin, Autosize.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Here is your fiddle updated with that plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/edZgm/3/

Just loaded the plugin and added this to your code.

```
    $('textarea')
    .autosize();
```