# HTML TextArea - Can I set height to fit content without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

Given the following text area;

```
<textarea textarea contentEditable="true">  
testing autoheight lkjul;khjfds
kjhkjghg

fgdgdsf
</textarea>
```

Is there a way I can set it height to fit the text? I've tried CSS;

```
height:auto;
```

But no luck

I've got this working with some JS;

```
const tx = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

for (let i = 0; i < tx.length; i++) {
  if (tx[i].value != ''){ 
    tx[i].setAttribute("style", "height:" + (tx[i].scrollHeight) + "px;overflow-y:hidden;");
  }
}
```

But it seems mad to me that there's no way to do this sans JS.

I've noticed other questions similar to mine (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955654/textarea-element-default-size-to-fit-content)) but they all mention JS solutions.

Is there a non JS solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea name="text" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"'></textarea>
```

Comment: Why does it make it super-lag when entering the text tho?

Answer (score -1):

You can set a wight and a height using the props "rows & cols" in the html

Anyway, it's more usefull to set this with javascript and css to make it responsive, but this is usefull to set a width and height :)

```html
For example:
<textarea id="Lorem" name="Lorem" rows="6" cols="50">Lorem impsu </textarea>
```